# App Canvas Pages Not Working

Tags: facebook, canvas

all of our Canvas Pages stopped working. For example: https://apps.facebook.com/paf-donations/. This leads to a page with the error code: Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error. Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your server's SSL certificate at https://fb.guidebycell.com/paf-donations/ expired. Ask your developers / admins to renew it

[image]